# nagios Not Found error

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

in log files and when apachectl restart show :

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/test/domains/suspended/crm] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/test/domains/suspended/crm] does not exist
```

httpd.conf :

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80

#LoadModule dummy_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_dummy.so
Include /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin admin@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

# Options and AllowOverrides
Include conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php index.php5 index.php4 index.php3 index.phtml index.cgi
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #replace %b with %O for more accurate logging
    <IfModule mod_logio.c>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
      LogFormat "%O %I" bytes

      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    # Include some DirectAdmin alias
    Include conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf
</IfModule>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler type-map var
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    AddType video/x-ms-asf .avi
    AddType video/mpeg .mpg
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg
    AddType video/quicktime .mov
    AddType video/x-ms-wmv .wmv
</IfModule>

#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off
```

i can not open nagios monitoring with url : serverip/nagios
404 not found

UPDATE: 
i create crm folder and document root error solved

but whean i brows ip/nagios display:

Not Found

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: @MadHatter solve error log and brows nagios

Comment: @MinA I'm not sure what you expect us to do for you here. You don't appear to have done any troubleshooting, and simply throwing an error message and a small chunk of your configuration on us and expecting us to Ouija Board a solution for you is *incredibly poor form*. Please invest some time in troubleshooting and investigating and post those results here if you want assistance from the community.

Comment: what you say? i create crm directory and error solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting the only main config file for apache. But you are obviously including a bunch of extra config files from (most likely) /etc/httpd/extra/* or /etc/httpd/conf.d/*

I cant find any references towards a config regarding a nagios directory you want to serve. Plus the warning states you are trying to configure something like a vhost with a documentroot pointing towards /home/test/domains/suspended/crm. But again I cant find references / configuration which shows what you did.

so check if you can find any *.conf files in any of those directories and have a look in those configs.

Comment: i dont understand anything